# Reopening already reviewed questions containing broken code

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This concerns [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/94351/14363) I (and then others) voted to close. It contains some bugs, which were found in [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94364/14363) by mdfst13. I wasn't sure if closing was a good idea and the current outcome says it was not:

> ... After the question has been edited to contain working code ...

IMHO the question should not be edited, as it'd invalidate the already given answer, which is good. At the same time, it makes no sense to post additional answers and the OP should start a new question after fixing the bugs. The question also should not be deleted as the answerer deserves their reputation.

But we have no "not deleted and not editable and not answerable" status, do we?

What's the proper cause of action?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the bugs necessarily make the question off-topic, if the author was unaware of the bugs.

Comment: @200_success Agreed. So it's on-topic, however, it shouldn't be reviewed anymore.

Answer (score 8):

> IMHO the question should not be edited, as it'd invalidate the already given answer, which is good.

Correct.

> At the same time, it makes no sense to post additional answers and the OP should start a new question after fixing the bugs.

Correct.

> The question also should not be deleted as the answerer deserves their reputation.

Correct.

> But we have no "not deleted and not editable and not answerable" status, do we?

On-hold / Closed.

I think the **best course of action** is to leave the question closed and suggest OP to post a follow-up.

> After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it.

This is one occasion where some text in the pre-written close reason does not match reality.

Comment: I completely agree. The risk of invalidating answers takes priority over improving the question in this case. A follow-up question by OP would be the appropriate action.

Comment: Change that sentence to be *"If the question has no answers, you can edit the question with working code and it may be reopened"* .... ?

Comment: @rolfl Although correct, I wonder if perhaps that "If the question has no answers" part would be confusing for new users. What do you think would happen if that part would be removed altogether?